# Removing Row from Kivy GridLayout or Refreshing GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy app that displays data from a pandas dataframe generated from the output of a windows command.

In the GirdLayout I have a button. I am trying to have the button remove a row from the GridLayout after it runs its command.
I have figured out how to remove the button from the GridLayout but can't seem to figure out the rest.

Alternatively refreshing the layout by rerunning the windows command and generating a new dataframe would also work.

I've looked at this answer but haven't been able to apply it to my code in a way that works.

[Kivy Removing elements from a Stack- / GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506407/kivy-removing-elements-from-a-stack-gridlayout)

```
def removeRow(self, instance):
    #This removes the button
    self.remove_widget(instance)

    #I've tried all 3 of these to refresh the GridLayout
    super(MakeTable, self).__init__()
    super(MakeTable, self).do_layout()
    MakeTable.do_layout(self)
```

My **init** for building the GridLayout

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    table = ["Stuff"]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(table)

    super(MakeTable, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 2
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
            btnremove = Button(text="Remove")
            btnremove.bind(on_press=self.removeRow)
            self.add_widget(btnremove)
            lblUser = Label(text=row['USERNAME'])
            self.add_widget(lblUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the container layout to a BoxLayout and changed my **init** to add the items to a GridLayout and then add it to the BoxLayout.
This allowed me to use remove_widget on the parent of the clicked button.

```
def removerow(self, instance):
    self.remove_widget(instance.parent)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    grid = GridLayout()
    grid.cols = 2
    lblUser = Label(text=row['USERNAME'])
    grid.add_widget(lblUser)
    lblServer = Label(text=row['SERVER'])
    grid.add_widget(lblServer)
    self.add_widget(grid)
```